# string representation of enum values

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.2 c89

I have the following enum:

```
enum drop_options_e
{
    drop_ssm,
    drop_snm,
    drop_ssb
};
```

I am just wondering that is the best way to get the string representation value from the enum.

So basically, instead of returning the value of 0 for drop_ssm, I could get the 'drop_ssm' instead.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to do like this:

```
enum drop_options_e
{
    drop_ssm = 0,
    drop_snm ,
    drop_ssb  ,
    LAST_ENTRY   /* Should be last entry */
};

const char* drop_options_s[LAST_ENTRY] = {"drop_ssm", "drop_snm", "drop_ssb"};
```

when you want a string representation of an enum you can `drop_options_s[enum];`

Comment: if this enum is used in more than one files, to make this work I needed to make drop_options_s static, and everytime enum file is included in another file, if drop_options_s is not referenced, I get a warning while compiling, is there a way that I can use it without all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Using [X-Macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#X-Macros) technique:

file `items`:

```
ITEM(drop_ssm)
ITEM(drop_snm)
ITEM(drop_ssb)
```

source:

```
#define ITEM(A) A,
enum drop_options_e
{
#include "items"
last
};
#undef ITEMS
#define ITEM(A) #A,
char item_names[] = {
#include "items"
NULL};
```

So now `item_names[drop_ssm]` will give you text string `"drop_ssm"`

Comment: This looks like a good answer. However, for simplicity I will have to go for Naveen answer.

Answer (score 3):

C has no support for that.  You will have to have a switch or equivalent somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a compiler that supports C99's designated initialisers, you can improve upon [Naveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543338/string-representation-of-enum-values/2543366#2543366):

```
enum drop_options_e
{
    drop_ssm,
    drop_snm,
    drop_ssb
};

#define ENUM_TO_S(e) [e] = #e

const char *drop_options_s[] = {
    ENUM_TO_S(drop_ssm),
    ENUM_TO_S(drop_snm),
    ENUM_TO_S(drop_ssb)
};
```

(With this method, you don't have to worry about the array initialisers being in the same order as the enum values).

Comment: It is so much better with X-Macros

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing out of the box. You can do some very interesting things with macros and Boost.Preprocessor, but it's quite involved, and I'm not sure how well it would work in C; I've done things in C++ that let me write, e.g.:

```
ENUM(
    ColorComponent,
    (red)
    (green)
    (blue)
    (alpha)
    );
// ...
ColorComponent cc = ColorComponent_red;
std::cout << "Color: " << toString(cc) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have see to handle this is to create a translation array.  Something like:

```
struct {
    enum drop_options_e value;
    char *string;
} TranslationArray[] = {
    drop_ssm, "drop_ssm",
    drop_snm, "drop_snm",
    drop_ssb, "drop_ssb",
};
```

This can be problematic if you're enum is quite large.

Answer (score -1):

I've so liked all answers here! During trying them I've found something very short and nice with BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE macro from boost:

```
//Define the enum you need
typedef enum
{
INTEGER = 0,
STRING  = 1,
BOOLEAN = 2,
}eValueType;

// Then in code use BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE, for example:
char* valueTypeStr = BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(INTEGER);
```

Comment: this will print `INTEGER`, why not just `char* valueTypeStr = "INTEGER"`?